# Home network questions, Create a new SE "Home network"

Tags: discussion

I have seen a lot of home related questions getting rejected according to the charter for this group, and that's OK.

To meet the need for home/amateur questions, could the solution be to create a new SE group? Input is welcome.

Comment: The real place to ask this question would be https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

What would be the benefit of yet another stack exchange group over asking on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com), where people asking questions about home networking are being referred to now.

These questions are [explicitly on topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) there:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> ```
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking
> ```

Adding more exchanges wouldn't make it any clearer in my opinion.

Comment: Good point! Thanks. And perhaps because the name "Super user" scares amateurs away?

Comment: Maybe, but that's not something we can change here.

Comment: @MatsK, I'm not sure why "Super User" would scare away amateurs, where "_professionally managed networks in a business environment_" would not.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have attempted this on Area51: [Home network](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/116183/home-network).

> **closed as duplicate of [Super User](http://superuser.com/) by [Robert Cartaino](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/5/robert-cartaino)♦ 8 hours ago**
>
> This subject is already well-covered by a live Stack Exchange site. We
>   generally do not split off subjects simply to give them their own
>   space.

I suppose you should have floated the idea on the Area51 Meta, first.